# How could I solve a system of equations of the form $xn_i^y+z=m_i$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

How could I solve the following system of equations:

$$xn_1^y+z=m_1$$
$$xn_2^y+z=m_2$$
$$xn_3^y+z=m_3$$
where $n_k$ and $m_k$ are parameters?

I am looking for an exact answer, but if it is not feasible, then a rough description of a numerical approach would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You will have to change your tags and question because this is not linear algebra problem. Linear algebra deals with systems of linear equations; linear equation have a form $a_1x_1 + ... a_nx_n=b$ where $a_i$ and $b$ are given and you search for $x_i$. Problem you described in nonlinear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After eliminating $x$ and $z$, you are left with  $(m_2 - m_3) n_1^y + (m_3 - m_1) n_2^y + (m_1 - m_2) n_3^y = 0$.  Unfortunately this won't have closed-form solutions in general; you'll have to rely on numerical methods.  The standard numerical equation-solvers could be used.  You might try Newton's Method if you're doing it yourself, but it's usually better to use existing tools if you have them available, e.g. **fsolve** in Maple.